# Overriding FOSUserBundle layout.html.twig when using a custom app path

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've followed [the instructions](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) for overriding the default layout.html.twig, but although my paths seem correct, the replacement template seems to be ignored.

I think this might be because I'm using a custom app path (`/app/web`) but as everything else appears to be working correctly, it seems strange that this would be the cause.

I have placed my alternate layout at `app/web/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig`

and the source is as follows:

```
{% extends 'AcmeWebBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there some way I can check which paths are being checked for an alternate template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind - I cleared the dev cache and it's now working, doh.